# Which driver to install for ATI ES1000 graphic card?

Tags: 12.04, ati

I am installing 12.04 on an IBM x3250 M2 server. It has an ATI ES1000 with no acceleration (that does not bother me, we don't need it), we use it to connect remotely via FreeNX.

FreeNX works fine, (except than in Windows 7 machines NX Client shows only icons and no text) but the only resolution I can get in the monitor directly attached to the server is 800x600. The display manager also shows me two monitors, the real one and one IBM 15".

Which driver should I install?. It seems that the ATI driver that comes with Ubuntu does not work properly. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does `xrandr` produce for the 800x600 monitor?

Answer (score 2):

From what I've found on this it looks like most people treat ATI ES1000 as the Radeon 7000.  This is still problematic, however, because their are no drivers around on ATI's website for the Radeon 7000.  That means that this card is legacy (and it even says so on their site).

So my recommendation is that you try using the open source X.Org driver.  This can be easily installed by going to the dash and typing **Additional Drivers**, and then selecting the X.Org open source driver from the list (I believe it is the top one).

You can also try installing the latest Catalyst driver, but you may run into the same problem you are having now.  Here is the link: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86

Answer (score 1):

I have an IBM x3250 M2 server too. It has an ATI ES1000 => YES

just update to version 14 of Ubuntu and it works fine even with 16 Mo on video.